# AWS S3 bucket versioning at the bucket level or directory level instead of object level

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, versioning

Is there a way to restore an AWS S3 bucket or directory inside a bucket to its previous version.

**Scenario where i find this useful is**

- upload a website, containing multiple directories and multiple files
  inside those directories into a aws s3 bucket with versioning and
  website hosting enabled.
- make code changes, upload latest code into
  the bucket
- if the build is bad, need to revert the s3 bucket to its old state quickly.

selecting 50+ files, for deletion, inside multiple directories that are marked as older versions is tedious and highly impossible.

Answer (score 1):

In general it's bad idea to not have continuous integration in front of deployment website content to bucket. Having any test runner which check your build before it's uploaded to S3 is much better approach.

Anyway I have a solution for you. Please upload to S3 content of your website packed as ZIP/TAR archive. If build would fail, you can grab previous version of the archive, and unpack it into the bucket.